# call internal endpoint when spring boot application run

Tags: spring-boot

I have an @RestController in my spring boot application, I want when run the app to call an endpoint in this controller.

What should I need to add in the app to call this endpoint ?

Comment: ....You are not supposed to be calling the REST API endpoint from internally.  It is meant for HTTP calls.   On the other hand, I am hoping you have isolated the code inside the actual rest implementation to a seperate (Service), and its own (Method), so then you can just call this service method yourself.

See simple example here https://github.com/smustafa/embedded-mongo-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/mongodb/embedded/demo/controller/UserController.java. 

So in your case, you call the UserService.getUserByID(), instead of calling the REST API Endpoint.